# LaTeX заменить подпись Figure на Рисунок

Tags: latex

Подскажите, как заменить "Figure 16" на "Рисунок 16" в подписи картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь пакетом `caption`. Добавьте в преамбулу следующие строки:

```
\usepackage{caption} %заголовки плавающих объектов

\captionsetup[figure]{name=Рисунок} %тут можно вписать много опций, но я оставил только касающуюся вопроса
```

Очень мощный пакет для заголовков плавающих объектов (рисунков и таблиц). Там много опций, но что конкретно Вам нужно - установите сами.

Мне даже попадалась как-то документация на русском языке, но ссылка была утеряна.

Comment: Спасибо!) То, что нужно.